# How can I define an Array of Strings in Ada?

Tags: arrays, string, warnings, ada

What I want is to define an array of Strings in Ada.

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
type String is array (Positive range <>) of Character;
type lexicon is array(1..7) of String(1..20);
nomFumadors : lexicon := ("Macia","Xisco","Toni","Laura","Rocky","Paz");
nomNoFumadors : lexicon := ("Marina","Marta","Joan","Africa","America");
```

And the compiler says:

```
warning:wrong length for array of subtype of "String" defined at line 42
```

My line 42 is this:

```
type lexicon is array(1..7) of String(1..20);
```

But compailer says the warning is in line 43 and 44: what are these:

```
nomFumadors : lexicon := ("Macia","Xisco","Toni","Laura","Rocky","Paz");
nomNoFumadors : lexicon := ("Marina","Marta","Joan","Africa","America");
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Standard disclaimer: the language discussed here is named for a woman and so should be capitalized as Ada.

Answer (score 6):

Others have mentioned bounded and unbounded strings.  You can also use Indefinite_Vectors.  You can use the "&" operator to initialize them (as opposed to the initializer list though the next version of Ada is adding initializer lists to containers).  You can use a vector just like an array by passing indexes in plus you get a lot of other additional functionality.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;

procedure Hello is

    package Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors
        (Index_Type   => Positive,
         Element_Type => String);
         
    use type Vectors.Vector;
         
    nomFumadors   : Vectors.Vector 
        := Vectors.Empty_Vector 
            & "Macia" 
            & "Xisco" 
            & "Toni" 
            & "Laura" 
            & "Rocky" 
            & "Paz";
    nomNoFumadors : Vectors.Vector
        := Vectors.Empty_Vector 
            & "Marina" 
            & "Marta" 
            & "Joan" 
            & "Africa" 
            & "America";
begin
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");
    
    -- Loop through Elements
    for Name of nomFumadors loop
        Put_Line(Name);
    end loop;
    
    -- Loop by index
    for Index in nomNoFumadors.Iterate loop
        Put_Line(nomNoFumadors(Index));
    end loop;
    
end Hello;
```

Answer (score 5):

You declared your array to hold Strings of length 20. The String literals you give are less than 20 Characters long. Hence the error.

You seem to be looking for a string type that contains a *maximum* of 20 characters. This is provided in `Ada.Strings.Bounded`:

```vhdl
package Max_20_String is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length (20);
use Max_20_String;

type Lexicon is array (1..7) of Bounded_String; -- from Max_20_String
nomFumadors : Lexicon := (To_Bounded_String ("Macia"),
                          To_Bounded_String ("Xisco"),
                          To_Bounded_String ("Toni"),
                          To_Bounded_String ("Laura"),
                          To_Bounded_String ("Rocky"),
                          To_Bounded_String ("Paz"));
```

To get back a String from a Bounded_String, use e.g. `To_String (Lexicon (2))`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is `Unbounded_String` (as its name suggests, length is variable and unlimited):

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Fumador is
  use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

  subtype VString is Unbounded_String;
  function "+" (Source : in String) return VString renames To_Unbounded_String;

  type Lexicon is array (Integer range <>) of VString;  --  Unknown number of people.
  nomFumadors : Lexicon := (+"Macia", +"Xisco", +"Toni", +"Laura", +"Rocky", +"Paz");
  nomNoFumadors : Lexicon := (+"Marina", +"Marta", +"Joan", +"Africa", +"America");
  
begin
  null;
end;
```

Comment: The function rename will of course work in both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use String, truncate long strings, and pad short strings:

```
Max : constant := 20;
subtype S20 is String (1 .. Max);
type Lexicon is array (1 .. 7) of S20;
function To20 (S : in String) return S20 is
   (if S'Length >= Max then S (S'First .. S'First + Max - 1)
    else S & (S'Length + 1 .. Max => ' ') );
V : Lexicon := (To20 (""), To20 ("Hello"), To20 ("1234567890123456789012345"), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jeff Carter's answer, but using a function to coerce any string into a fixed string ...

```
procedure Main is
   
   subtype Lexicon_Data is String (1 .. 20);
   type Lexicon is array (1 .. 7) of Lexicon_Data;
   
   function To_Lexicon_Data
     (Value : in String)
      return Lexicon_Data
   is
      Result : Lexicon_Data;
   begin
      
      if Value'Length < 1 then
         -- Empty string returns a bunch of spaces
         Result := (others => ' ');
         
      else
         declare
            Offset : constant Natural :=
              Value'First - Lexicon_Data'First;
         begin
            
            if Value'Length > Lexicon_Data'Length then
               -- Length exceeds range, so truncate
               Result (Lexicon_Data'Range) := Lexicon_Data
                 (Value (Offset + 1 .. Offset + Lexicon_Data'Length));

            else
               -- Copy into result, and pad right with spaces
               Result := (others => ' ');
               Result (Lexicon_Data'First .. Value'Length) :=
                 (Value (Offset + 1 .. Offset + Value'Length));

            end if;
      
         end;
         
      end if;
               
      return Result;
         
   end To_Lexicon_Data;
   
   
   nomFumadors : constant Lexicon :=
     (To_Lexicon_Data ("Macia"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Xisco"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Toni"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Laura"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Rocky"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Paz"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Mark"));
     
begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

If you wanted to prove AoRTE (ie SparkAda) then the declaration for Result in the function becomes

```
Result : Lexicon_Data
   with Relaxed_Initialization;
```

.. and the function To_Lexicon_Data is proved as being runtime error free.

Note the extra item for Lexicon, Mark, since you need seven items for the Lexicon declaration to be valid.

Comment: This could be simplified using Ada.Strings.Fixed.Move: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Strings.Fixed

Comment: Or even better, use Ada.Strings.Fixed.Head. I think I'm going to provide that as another alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the solution by Mark, but simplifying thanks to the operations from [`Ada.Strings.Fixed`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Strings.Fixed).

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   
   subtype Lexicon_Data is String (1 .. 20);
   type Lexicon is array (1 .. 7) of Lexicon_Data;
   
   function To_Lexicon_Data
     (Value : in String)
      return Lexicon_Data
   is
   begin
      return Ada.Strings.Fixed.Head (Value, Lexicon_Data'Length);
   end To_Lexicon_Data;
   
   
   nomFumadors : constant Lexicon :=
     (To_Lexicon_Data ("Macia"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Xisco"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Toni"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Laura"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Rocky"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Paz"),
      To_Lexicon_Data ("Mark"));
     
begin
   
   for Item of nomFumadors loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (Item, Ada.Strings.Both));
   end loop;
   
end Main;
```